# Por que esta resposta foi apagada?

Tags: debate

[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134347/problemas-ao-passar-uma-lista-de-objetos-para-outra-lista/134349) tem [uma resposta removida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134349/1658).

Para aqueles que não podem vê-la, eis seu conteúdo, *verbatim*:

> Quando o relacionamento é de muito pra muitos você tem que fazer uma tabela extra pra poder relacionar os dois. Uma tabela contendo a chave das duas tabelas e um id próprio.
>
> Pelo que entendi você tem uma tabela de estados e outra tabela de pessoas. Uma pessoa pode estar em vários estados. Então são várias pessoas pra vários estados.
>
> Faça uma tabela extra que faça essa ligação.
>
> Você tem uma tabela pessoa exemplo: PessoaId Nome
>
> Uma tabela de Estado: EstadoId NomedoEstado
>
> E faça uma tabela relacional ListaEstado: ListadeEstadoId PessoaId EstadoId
>
> Lembrando que o campo PessoaId e o Campo EstadoId são chaves estrangeiras.

Acredito que não é uma resposta perfeita, mas também não é uma resposta sem salvação. O autor ou alguém com tempo livre nas mãos poderia formatar melhor a resposta, que é semelhante em ideia a outra resposta da pergunta que inclusive já teve voto positivo.

Comment: Excluir foi unanimidade na fila de análise de baixa qualidade: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/69262

Comment: Uma parte dos votos foi antes da edição, quando a resposta tinha formato de comentário.